# I have added Channel to my NotificationManager and Builder, but my Activity is still not opened on tapping the notification

Tags: android, kotlin

Following are my code:

```
    private val CHANNEL_ID = "Test"
    private val CHANNEL_NAME = "Test_Name"

    val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            CHANNEL_ID,
            CHANNEL_NAME,
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        )
        channel.description = "Description"
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    val intent = Intent(
            context,
            WebViewActivity::class.java
        )
    val contentIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 2, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
    val builder: NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(body)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(null)
        .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)

    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build())
```

Comment: Does the `Notification` get dismissed when you click on it? Your title here suggests that the `Notification` did at least show before you added the channel. Is that correct? Which Android version are you testing on?

Comment: @MikeM. Oops I forgot to mention I am using Android 10 now. Everything works fine (including dismissal upon click), except the navigation to my `WebViewActivity`.

Comment: Are you seeing anything in [your logs](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat#running)? Can you successfully launch `WebViewActivity` directly yourself? That code appears to be in a `Context` class, since you're calling `getSystemService()` directly. If so, why do you have a separate `context` variable, in the `Intent` instantiation? Are you sure it's not null?

Comment: Yes I have another screen that also redirects to `WebViewActivity` upon list view item click. I put this code in my class that extends `FirebaseMessagingService` btw...

Comment: Never mind that last one. I just remembered that it would throw an NPE at instantiation, if that were null.

Comment: Hmm, well, I don't think I have anything else to suggest, at this point. I've not done a lot with Android 10 specifics yet, but I don't think that there were any significant changes in the `Notification` API. I would guess that it's something to do with 10's restriction on starting Activities while your app is backgrounded, but I thought that just having the `Notification` would qualify your app to do that.

Comment: @MikeM. after I further researched, I found that actually caused when my application is killed or in background, as the PN need to be handled differently by getting the payload from bundle in the launched activity.

Comment: Cool. Glad you got it figured out. Cheers!